# Use jQuery prepend to add div element

Tags: jquery

I wonder if it's possible to have several div elements with different id that has different contents and then add them with prepend depending of the choice from a menu? When the page load, all of these element should be hidden. Could I do that?

EDIT:
Instead of load several different pages with just some text, but with different subject, my idea was to have all info on one page and just show the some parts depending on the user choice. Is this a bad idea?

Comment: I downvoted and the answer to this question is clearly YES or NO. Can you please clarify what you need and what you couldn't here at SO?

Comment: Why you want to **prepend a div**, to what element? Don't you want just show a div based on some conditions?

Comment: Sad if you have to downvote my question! I could perhaps be a little mer clear. I just wanted som help with the code how I should hide the elements and how I should add them with prepend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ilecik/2/edit)**

Create all your *menu* and *box* elements:

```
<ul id="menu">
   <li>1</li>
   <li>2</li>
   <li>3</li>
</ul>

<div class="box">Box 1</div>
<div class="box">Box 2</div>
<div class="box">Box 3</div>
```

Make sure your boxes are CSS:

```
display:none;
```

Than simply do:

```
$(function(){
   $('#menu li').click(function(){
        var menuLiIndex = $(this).index();
        $('.box').hide().eq( menuLiIndex ).show();
   });
});
```

Comment: I guess hide and show is better! I had forgot that thoose was available. I guess that is the help I was looking for. Can I also combine the hiding and showing process with soma fading?

Comment: Great demo! Just like I want it!